# Loading HTML file with jquery.load(), then accessing parameters in loaded HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameters, load

Im developing a Javascript-only app. I have an html page from which I want to load a second html page, passing some parameters to it. In the second page, I want to access these parameters.

Javascript in page1.html:

```
  var url = "page2.html?foo=bar";
  jQuery("body").load(url);
```

This loads page2.html, but how can I access the foo parameter in page2.html?

Comment: Tried this ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js

Comment: My question is not how to exctract the foo parameter from the URL string, that's trivial. I want to know how to access the complete URL itself, including foo=bar, from page2.html. 
I cannot use window.location.href, as that only returns page1.html.

Comment: Only server will know what parameters were passed for requesting somethig since js cannot interact with the server i'm afraid this can't be done unless you have some server-side code(php,java,python etc) embedded in page2.html that would tell js inside page2.html about parameters it was requested with.

Comment: You have to use the load callback function. jQuery("body").load(url, function(){ //in here you can pull the parameter like you would normally }); (I think)

Comment: @Novice Yes, it could be easily achieved with php, but I was hoping this would be possible with jQuery's load() (or ajax) method.

Comment: @Chris I've tried that. The parameters are not available in the success function of load().

Comment: where is the parameter generated in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl The parameter is generated in page1.html. I want it to be available to page2.html when page2 is loaded.

Comment: You should still have the variables available then because you are just replacing the body you are not actually navigating away or refreshing the page.

Comment: @Chris I guess you're right, but my actual app is much more complex than this simple example. It would be very much easier if I shomehow could access the parameter being sent.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible (?) to do get the parameters the way I want. But I found an acceptable workaround: I use **localStorage** to set and get the parameters instead of sending them to `load()`.

I.e., in `page1.html`, I do:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
```

and in `page2.html`, I do:

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("foo");
```